# Expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'int32_t'

Tags: c, compiler-errors

Heads up, this is for a class assignment so, you know, academic honesty and whatnot.

I have a struct defined like this:

```
typdef struct {
    int32_t r[8];
    Seq_T m;
    Seq_T lengths;
    int32_t ctr;
} UM_T;
```

Everything was compiling fine, including the implementation, until I added a client:

```
#include "um.h"

int main(int argv, char* argc[]){                                                    
    FILE* file = fopen(argc[1]);                                                     
    UM_T* um = UM_new (file);                                                        
    run(um);                                                                         
};
```

Now the compiler (gcc) tells me:

```
um.h:5: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'int32_t'
```

I would have some idea what to do if `int32_t` were a struct or something I'd defined, but obviously that's not the case. Any ideas?

Comment: `#include <stdint.h>` so the compiler knows the type.

Answer (score 1):

```
FILE* file = fopen(argc[1]);
```

`fopen` function has two parameters but you are only passing one argument.

Then:

```
    run(um);
};

 ^
```

You have to remove the trailing `;`.

And also be sure to include `stdio.h` for `fopen` and `stdint` for `int32_t` type.

Finally:

```
int main(int argv, char* argc[])
```

you probably meant:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

to avoid confusions.

Then of course you will have to use `argv[1]` instead of `argc[1]` in your `fopen` call.

Comment: Regarding the final remark, the OP is using `argc[1]`, so at least that's consistent (though of course one should not do that).

Comment: @DanielFischer yes, I should maybe add that he also has to fix `fopen` regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

```
FILE *fopen(const char *path, const char *mode);
```

The above is the declaration of `fopen()`.It requires two parameters but you are passing 
only one.

It will give you error message:

```
too few arguments to function ‘fopen’
```

And also in the struct you are using `int32_t` so include  or `<sys/types.h>`